# How can I list all my comments or at least WI I worked on?

Tags: tfs

I have met a problem which I had already solved during the last month or two. And that time I had written the solution in a comment. How can I find it using the browser?

A list of all my comments or all WI I worked on would be OK.  Of course, these items do not belong to me now. Even better if the list would be limited or ordered by time.

Comment: How did you add the comment? In a Code Review? If in a code review, do you add the comment in VS or in web portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a work item query, and set `Assigned To` field  `Was Ever` to you, to list the work items that were assigned to you before:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was a great help and inspiration, too!